# Calculate percentage from single column without variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have following table in sql server

```
HEAD    | COL1  | COL2
------------------------
MARKS   | 546   | 798
TOTAL   | 1000  | 1000
PERCENT | NULL  | NULL
```

I want to populate result like below by query. Please help me

```
HEAD    | COL1  | COL2
------------------------
MARKS   | 546   | 798
TOTAL   | 1000  | 1000
PERCENT | 54.6  | 79.8
```

Comment: Your data structure is not ideal. Your columns should be rows and rows should be columns [like this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/01681).

Comment: i know very well but it is not possible for me to make it ideal. sorry.

Comment: @hims056 the last line in your fiddle is wrong and you are using the wrong types, use int for the numeric values. However i agree the tablestructure in the question is terrible and should be reworked

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - Yeah I just wanted to give idea to the OP. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Not going to accept your tabel structure. It is reversed and hurt my eyes. Writing a solution to your table structure will only cure the symptom, I am trying to cure the real problem.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
([head] varchar(10), [marks] INT, [total] INT, [pct] as cast(100.0*marks / total as numeric(4,1)))

INSERT INTO Table1(head, marks, total)
VALUES ('Col1', 546, 1000),('Col2', 798, 1000)

SELECT head, marks, total FROM Table1
```

Result:

```
head  marks  total  pct
Col1  546    1000   54.6
Col2  798    1000   79.8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update tablename set
col1 = c1, col2 = c2 from
(
Select x.col1*100./y.col1 c1, x.col2*100./y.col2 c2 from
(select * from TableName where head='mark') x
cross join 
(select * from TableName where head='total') y
 ) z
where head = 'percent';
```

Comment: do you see any problems if total or mark change value. Percent will change however not it will not reflect in this method ?